# how to manager timer task such heartbeat in network programming?

Tags: network-programming, netty

I'm learning TCP programming by write a java/scala socket library and want to know how to design a heart beat.
For some research, there refers two technology, 1. timer task dispath and 2. task scheduler.

In netty source code, there are `Read/WriteTimeoutHandler` and `HashedWheelTimer` class. I want to know how does netty work with it?
As a guess, does netty record latest message send/write time and use `HashedWheelTimer` to scheduler `Read/WriteTimeoutHandler` as a timer task to check timeout?

I not family with netty framework yet and just want to know how does netty manager timer task.

besides netty, welcome any other design thought about how to desgin a heartbeat.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kind of correct... The only thing that is not correct is the usage of `HashedWheelTimer` here. Netty uses the `EventLoop` to schedule the task 4.x which also ensures everything is handled within the `EventLoop` thread.